# Restrict access to USB ports by type in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, permissions, configuration, users, restricted-access

How to limit access to any USB port by device type? For e.g. if I need to insert just my own mouse but no others? Is it possible to get somehow the usb device type (mouse,keyboard,drive) and it's id (or serial number) and then register this device so that no other devices will have access except this one? All I want to do is to "register" only my mouse and open access for all usb flash drives so any other inserted usb devices should not have access to my PC (4g modems, webcams, keyboards, e.t.c)

Comment: That is a good idea. New devices should cause a popup asking if you want to authorize that device for that port ("Trust on first use" - TOFU).

Comment: Sorry, but I think there is no popups for any additional inserted mouse or keyboard via usb. Such devices start to work instantly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of udev.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man7/udev.7.html

Using rules you can identify devices and trigger actions when they're inserted or removed.

I have small USB key containing my certificates.When I plug it on any of my PCs, my session is unlocked, the key is mounted in my homedir allowing me to authenticate myself on several services.

Comment: Thank you a lot. That is what I looking for. So, what option of udev should response for usb device type (keyboard, mouse, scaner, webcam, flashdrive)? Could somebody give me a simple example how to allow access for a mouse with specific id only, please?

Comment: @mr.boris I do not think it exists, but it is a good idea, and would be a natural extension of `udev`.

Comment: So, udev needs to be upgraded by linux devs, right?

Comment: @mr.boris Yes: You should contact the developers of udev and pitch the idea to them.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial about writing udev rules:

Comment: Here is a good tutorial about writing udev rules:
http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

It's quite easy to write basic rules that will fulfill your needs.

If you wish extra security about the devices that can be connected to your PC, uninstall every driver you don't need (mind the dependencies!)

If you wish Fort Knox security, compile your own kernel. This is a good thing to try anyway if you wish to learn a bit more how your PC works, what is a driver...